# Change column type Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Why did I get the following errors

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL  
   COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1 (SQL: ALTER TABLE questions CHANGE category_id category_id INT DEFAULT  NOT NULL COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci)

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL  
   COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1
```

By executing the following code:

```
Schema::table('questions', function(Blueprint $table) {
     $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->change();
});
```

Comment: I think you have null values in your table

Comment: can you please post the migration that you had before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `unsignedInteger` instead

```
Schema::table('questions', function(Blueprint $table) {
   $table->unsignedInteger('category_id')->change();
});
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why this would solve the issue, since Laravel's Schema Builder would generate **the exact same statement** as the OP's definition (but without using Fluent for chaining the `unsigned` property).